# xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2

HI I was trying to login remotely in the computer hosted by amazon services. It's ubuntu 64 bit machine.
In the beginning I was able to login into the computer with both client , remote desktop connection (RDP) keeping the default port (-1) and for the command line I am using putty session to access the computer. But after we made some changes and create new images of computer state. But When I try to login again it gives me the error xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed.
So I was wondering is that related with the port number ? or some image creation issue.
I will look forward to hear from you.

Thanks
Yash

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue. The solution to me is just to create new user for xrdp. While user "ubuntu" worked on original instance. After launching a new instance using a snapshot of the original instance, "ubuntu" login didn't work anymore. Then, after creating a new user, I could login with the new user onto xrdp.